# Join three list using multiple columns c# linq lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

I have these lists:

```
var subjects = new List<SubjectModel>
        {
            new SubjectModel { subjId = 1, subjName = "Math" },
            new SubjectModel { subjId = 2, subjName = "Science" },
            new SubjectModel { subjId = 3, subjName = "History" },
            new SubjectModel { subjId = 4, subjName = "Language" }
        };

var quizzes = new List<QuizModel>
        {
            new QuizModel { quizId = 1, quizDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), quizScore = 10, subjectId = 1 },
            new QuizModel { quizId = 2, quizDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), quizScore = 15, subjectId = 1 },
            new QuizModel { quizId = 3, quizDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), quizScore = 8, subjectId = 2 },
            new QuizModel { quizId = 4, quizDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-26"), quizScore = 13, subjectId = 1 },
            new QuizModel { quizId = 5, quizDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-26"), quizScore = 20, subjectId = 2 }
        };

var exams = new List<ExamModel>
        {
            new ExamModel { examId = 1, examDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), examScore = 90, subjectId = 1 },
            new ExamModel { examId = 2, examDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), examScore = 88, subjectId = 2 },
            new ExamModel { examId = 3, examDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), examScore = 92, subjectId = 4 },
            new ExamModel { examId = , examDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-26"), examScore = 84, subjectId = 1 },

        };

var exercises = new List<ExerciseModel>
        {
            new ExerciseModel { exerciseId = 1, exerciseDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), exerciseScore = 17, subjectId = 1 }, 
            new ExerciseModel { exerciseId = 2, exerciseDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), exerciseScore = 15, subjectId = 2 },
            new ExerciseModel { exerciseId = 3, exerciseDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-26"), exerciseScore = 15, subjectId = 1 },
            new ExerciseModel { exerciseId = 4, exerciseDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-26"), exerciseScore = 12, subjectId = 4 },
            new ExerciseModel { exerciseId = 5, exerciseDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-26"), exerciseScore = 10, subjectId = 1 },
        };
```

I was able to successfully group each of them by date and by subject.

```
var allQuizzes = quizzes.GroupBy(qz => qz.quizDate, (q, values) =>
            new
            {
                Date = q,
                Quizzes = values.GroupBy(v => v.subjectId, (c, values2) => 
                    new { 
                        SubjectId = c, 
                        QuizSum = values2.Sum(v2 => v2.quizScore) 
                    })
            });

var allExercises = exercises.GroupBy(ex => ex.exerciseDate, (e, values) =>
            new {
                Date = e,
                Exercises = values.GroupBy(x => x.subjectId, (z, values2) =>
                    new {
                        SubjectId = z,
                        ExerSum = values2.Sum(r => r.exerciseScore)
                    })
            });

var allExams = exams.GroupBy(ex => ex.examDate, (e, values) =>
            new
            {
                Date = e,
                Exercises = values.GroupBy(x => x.subjectId, (z, values2) =>
                    new
                    {
                        SubjectId = z,
                        ExamSum = values2.Sum(r => r.examScore)
                    })
            });
```

However, I need to join all three of them to get the sum of all scores. The final table should display like this.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|      Date     |  Math  |  Science  |   History   |  Language  |
|   11/25/2016  |   132  |      111  |         0   |        92  |
|   11/26/2016  |   122  |       20  |         0   |        12  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to join them, but it can't seem to join by multiple columns.

Comment: You have to search for Pivot

Comment: @irenebelserion1 Do you have some feedback,  If answers do help / doesn't help you ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I select from all 3 collections results in form of the same anonymous class (the same Idea had Andrei in first answer), that allows me just to collect all results together in all list, without mapping and converting.

```
var allQuiz = quizzes.GroupBy(x => new { x.subjectId, x.quizDate })
                     .Select(x => new {
                          Date = x.Key.quizDate, 
                          Subj = x.Key.subjectId, 
                          Sum = x.Sum(r=>r.quizScore)});

var allExam= exams.GroupBy(x => new { x.subjectId, x.examDate })
                     .Select(x => new {
                          Date = x.Key.examDate, 
                          Subj = x.Key.subjectId, 
                          Sum = x.Sum(r=>r.examScore)});

var allExc = exercises.GroupBy(x => new { x.subjectId, x.exerciseDate })
                     .Select(x => new {
                          Date = x.Key.exerciseDate, 
                          Subj = x.Key.subjectId, 
                          Sum = x.Sum(r=>r.exerciseScore)});
```

Combining of all results together:

```
var all = allQuiz.ToList();
all.AddRange(allExam.ToList());
all.AddRange(allExc.ToList());

var result = all.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date, x.Subj })
                .Select(x => new { x.Key.Date, x.Key.Subj, Sum = x.Sum(s => s.Sum)});

var list = result.GroupBy(r => r.Date).Select(x => new {
       Date = x.Key, 
       Math = x.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Subj==1)?.Sum ?? 0,
       Science = x.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Subj==2)?.Sum ?? 0,
       History = x.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Subj==3)?.Sum ?? 0,
       Language = x.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Subj==4)?.Sum ?? 0,
       });
```

Output in LinqPad:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thanks for this. I did modified a few lines, I keep getting error on SingleorDefault() part.

Comment: @irenebelserion1 Thanks. I would be thankfull for an upvote too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. Instead of keeping the distinction while grouping, you could convert all three to the same structure. For instance:

```
var allQuizzes = quizzes.GroupBy(qz => qz.quizDate, (q, values) =>
        new
        {
            Date = q,
            Results = values.GroupBy(v => v.subjectId, (c, values2) => 
                new { 
                    SubjectId = c, 
                    Sum = values2.Sum(v2 => v2.quizScore) 
                })
        });
```

Notice names "Results" and "Sum" - you can use the same for the other two objects. And now you have three collections, all of the same structure:

```
{
    Date:
    Results: [
         {SubjectId, Sum}
         {SubjectId, Sum}
         ...
    ]
}
```

Since they are all the same now, you can stop treating them differently, use UNION to merge all three, group them by date and within that by subject. Then you could probably iterate through subject list to get necessary info, depends on what you mean by "final table".

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with.
It may not be best optimized, but might be enough for you.
I rendered the results into a StringBuilder in my test.

```
var result =
quizzes.Select(q => new {SubjectId = q.subjectId, Date = q.quizDate, Score = q.quizScore})
    .Union(exams.Select(e => new {SubjectId = e.subjectId, Date = e.examDate, Score = e.examScore}))
    .Union(exercises.Select(e => new {SubjectId = e.subjectId, Date = e.exerciseDate, Score = e.exerciseScore}))
    .GroupBy(arg => arg.Date,
    (key, values)=> 
    new
    {
        Key = key,
        Scores = values.GroupBy(v => v.SubjectId, (s, values2) => new { SubjectId = s, SumScore = values2.Sum(v2 => v2.Score) })
    });

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Date\t\t");
foreach (SubjectModel subject in subjects)
{
    sb.Append($"{subject.subjName}\t");
}

sb.AppendLine();

foreach (var record in result)
{
    sb.Append($"{record.Key.ToShortDateString()}\t");
    foreach (SubjectModel subject in subjects)
    {
        int sum = record.Scores.Where(s => s.SubjectId == subject.subjId).Select(s => s.SumScore).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Single();
        sb.Append($"{sum}\t");
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
}

string finalTable = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using three different anonymous objects to hold the results, make your own class:

```
public enum TestType
{
    Quiz,
    Exam,
    Exercise,
}

public class TestScore
{
    public TestType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int      Score { get; set; }
    public int      SubjectId { get; set; }

    // Constructors - make a TestScore object

    public TestScore(QuizModel q)
    {
        Type      = TestType.Quiz;
        Date      = q.quizDate;
        Score     = q.quizScore;
        SubjectId = q.SubjectId;            
    }

    public TestScore(ExamModel e)
    {
        Type      = TestType.Exam;
        Date      = e.examDate;
        Score     = e.examScore;
        SubjectId = e.SubjectId;            
    }

    public TestScore(ExerciseModel e)
    {
        Type      = TestType.Exercise;
        Date      = e.exerciseDate;
        Score     = e.exerciseScore;
        SubjectId = e.SubjectId;            
    }
}
```

Convert to TestScore:

```
List<TestScore> scores = new List<TestScore>();

scores.AddRange(quizzes.Select(q => new TestScore(q));
scores.AddRange(exams.Select(e => new TestScore(e));
scores.AddRange(exercises.Select(e => new TestScore(e));
```

Now you have one datasource instead of three, displaying the results becomes easy.